# Angular data isn't posting in postman api

Tags: angular

I am posting data in postsman api but it isn't working why ?? someday tell me what i am doing wrong?
My api is 
http://dradiobeats.x10host.com//api/areas

my  file-upload.component.html is

```html
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    

        <div class="form-group input-group-lg">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="id.." formControlName="id">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg">Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

my  file-upload.component.ts is

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload',
  templateUrl: './file-upload.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-upload.component.css']
})

export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],

    })
  }

  ngOnInit() { }


  submitForm() {
    var data: any = {id: this.form.get('id').value}
    this.http.post('http://dradiobeats.x10host.com//api/areas', data).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    )
  }

}
```

How can i post data into postman api plzz someday tell me!!

Comment: you have two slashes in your url http://dradiobeats.x10host.com`//`api/areas

Comment: Define "it isn't working". What happens **precisely**. Include any error message you might see in the console.

Comment: @JBNizet HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com//api/areas/", ok: false, …}

Comment: That probably is a CORS error. Does the API you're using (http://dradiobeats.x10host.com) accept CORS requests, i.e. requests coming from scripts loaded from another domain than x10host.com?

Comment: @JBNizet http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: @JBNizet there is no error of cors

Comment: Do you get a status 401, or a status 0? 0 is most probably a CORS error. 401 means you must be authenticated.

Comment: Status 401 so how i resolve this @JBNizet

Comment: By authenticating. The documentation of the API you're using should explain it. But why does the error you posted say `status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error"` if what you get is a 401? How do you know you get a 401?

Comment: @JBNizet   HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas", ok: false, …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 401
statusText: "Unauthorized"
url: "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure response for http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas: 401 Unauthorized"
error: {message: "Unauthenticated."}
__proto__: HttpResponseBase

Comment: OK. So read the documentation of the API to know how to authenticate.